# Newbie Question: Supposedly Inaccurate Measurements

Tags: measurement

I tried to make my measurements as accurate as possible, but blender still mucks it up.

[image: Picture]

As seen in the photo, each stair step (tread) is measured as 30cm, so I made a hexagonal prism with a radius of 10cm. I then placed the prism in the middle of the step, subtracting 10 from 30 and dividing it by 2, so there should be 10cm of space on the left and right of the prism.

Anyways, I'm straying away from the point. Left side of the prism measures 10cm but right side of the prism measures 9.99999 for some reason. Any ideas why this is the case and how to fix it?

Comment: Well, it depends on different things, like how you created it, how you measure it and then there is floating point inaccuracy as well. First of all you have to accept that Blender is not a CAD software.  Then the point ist, how exact the measuring tool gets this value. I for example selected a face with a width of 0.3 m, snapped the cursor to the selection and placed a hexagon there with a radius of 0.05 to get the 0.1 width. I cut the 0.3 face exactly through the center of the hexagon, divided the cut in three segments and snapped the vertices to the hexagon corners.

Comment: Then I enabled the _Edge Length_ overlay in the viewport and selected those edges, they all showed 0.1 m, summing up to 0.3 m. Then I selected the two corner vertices of the hexagon and pressed J to connect them. The length on this edge also showed 0.1 m, so there everything seems to be okay. And I used the _Measure_, making sure I snap to the vertices and edges and constraining it to the axis to make sure I measure it straight - and it also showed the correct values.

Comment: So, I cannot reproduce your issue, but I can tell you there are several ways to get incorrect results, like inaccurate construction and inaccurate measuring from the user down to floating point inaccuracies, where the last one is something which you cannot do anything about it, and this floating point inaccuracy can be effecting either the construction or the measuring or both as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question @GordonBrinkmann. I think it might be in the way I made it, just as you say. I also made a seperate face and tried to copy what you did to the best of my abilities, and surprisingly, this one measures correctly. Left side measures 10cm and right side also measures 10cm. You see, the way I made the stairs is by making cube meshes and attaching them to each other using _Dissolve Edges_, but I can't exactly say if that's the reason for the inaccuracy.

Comment: That might be a reason, or at least it's not impossible.